# Convert Byte array to Int in xamarin pcl c#

Tags: c#, arrays, xamarin.forms, byte, portable-class-library

this is my problem: i need to convert bytes array to int in c#, on xamarin pcl.
But i have tryed this:

```
byte[] fromBoardSerial = new byte[3];
fromBoardSerial[0] = 0x04
fromBoardSerial[1] = 0x93
fromBoardSerial[2] = 0xe0

result = BitConverter.ToInt32(fromBoardSerial, 0);
```

**Solution**:

```
Array.Reverse(fromBoardSerial); //call before conversion
```

but the **result** is: -527236096...Instead..***the correct result should be: 300000***
how do conversion from array bytes in Int ?

Thanks

Comment: There must be something wrong an integer consists of 4 bytes?

Comment: yes is correct...if you will try it: http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have two problems here:

1. Number of bytes. You must have 4 bytes for conversion to Int32.
2. Byte order. It looks like you try to calculate your number "backwards".

Look at this code:

```
byte[] fromBoardSerial = new byte[4];
fromBoardSerial[0] = 0xe0;
fromBoardSerial[1] = 0x93;
fromBoardSerial[2] = 0x04;
fromBoardSerial[3] = 0x00;

var result = BitConverter.ToInt32(fromBoardSerial, 0); // result = 300000
```

Comment: i solved with this: Array.Reverse(fromBoardSerial); and after bit conversione...if you update the answer i check right answer